# java.lang.NullPointerException When calling an int array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am very new to java and I have been stuck on this for a few hours now. Whevenever I try to call organizeBallots() I get the exception. From what I read, I have not initialized regionBallots correctly or that something is null. To me, it looks like I have initialized the array correctly and since its an int, it should be 0, not null. ...But I guess Im wrong, any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: As I said I am new so Im not sure if it helps, but organizeBallots() is being called by another method in another class.

```
int[] regionBallots;        
regionBallots = new int[9];



public int[] organizeBallots( int incoming )
{

    if ( incoming >= 1 && incoming <= 10 )
        regionBallots[0]++;    // I get the exception here

    else if ( incoming >= 11 && incoming <= 20 )
        regionBallots[1]++;


    return regionBallots;

}
```

Comment: Where are the first two lines located?  What method?

Comment: What exception you get? NullPointerException? Try to System.out.println(regionalBallots) to check if it is null.

Comment: the first line is a decleration at the beginning of the class while the second line is in the constructor of the same class. @PiotrKochanski yeah its a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

Make it like this: `int[] regionBallots = new int[9];`

You can't write code outside methods, except in initializers.
To use an initializer write:

```
{
  //here the initializing code
}
```

To use a static initializer write:

```
static {
    //here the static initializing code
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that result in a compiler error, rather than an exception as the OP stated?

Comment: -1: this is patently false. Java supports expressions in field initialisers.

Comment: @Inerdial - Yes, but he hasn't put the code in an initialiser.

Comment: I do `Set foo = new HashSet();` to declare fields all the time. That's not where the problem is.

Comment: @Inerdial - The OP hasn't given enough information. I am pointing out the mistake in the posted code.

Comment: Yes, the OP hasn't given enough info. My guess is he's initializing `regionBallots` in a constructor but calling `organizeBallots` before he manages to do that.

Comment: ^ there. I initialize it in the constructor. Constructors confuse the Sh@t outta me and I think I recieved an error unless it was initialized that way.

Comment: But it's obvious that the problem the OP is describing in not a syntax error. Therefore your answer does not actually solve the OP's problem. If the code sample in the question is wrong, pointing this out belongs in the question comments.

Comment: @Inerdial - I completely agree with you. I should have posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me without any issues:

```
public class T {

    int[] regionBallots;

    public T() {
        regionBallots = new int[9];
    }

    public int[] organizeBallots(int incoming) {

        if (incoming >= 1 && incoming <= 10)
            regionBallots[0]++; //

        else if (incoming >= 11 && incoming <= 20)
            regionBallots[1]++;

        return regionBallots;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T t = new T();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {         
              System.out.println(t.organizeBallots(i));
              System.out.println(t.organizeBallots(i)[0]);
              System.out.println(t.organizeBallots(i)[1]); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what did you do differently? This looks like exactly what I did haha

Comment: Hard to say. I did not see any problem with your code. Try to debug your code to see if regionBallots is not null in organizeBallots method.